# Function to replace multiple whitespaces with single whitespace in redshift | tried replace() not working

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to replace multiple whitespaces from a column in Redshift

Query used :

```
Select replace(col_name,'  ',' ') from table;
```

above query is not working for multiple whitespaces only.

I have tried replacing other characters in the same query, also for a single whitespace it's working fine.

Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all occurrences of multiple whitespaces with a single whitespace:

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE('a phrase   with    multiple  whitespaces', '\\s+', ' ')
---

a phrase with multiple whitespaces
```

Comment: again same issue, this is working for every scenario but not for double whitespaces, I think there is some encoding issue in that column. the method is not considering it as a whitespace

Comment: @HarshShukla: please post the output of `SELECT  col_name, FROM_VARBYTE(col_name::VARBYTE, 'HEX')` for the relevant string

Comment: Yes, thats's the issue, where I am getting whitespace varbyte as '2020', it is replacing , but in some cases I am getting whitespace varbyte as 'c2a020', here the query is not working, Any suggestions for this,  Sorry cant share col name here

Answer (score 0):

Try the regular expression:

```
select regexp_replace (col_name, '( ){2,}',' ','g') from table_name;
```